# Iterate dataframe column Array of Array in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to iterate over an array of array as a column in Spark dataframe. Looking for the best way to do this.

Schema:

```
root
 |-- Animal: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Species: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mammal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
```

Currently I am using this logic. This only gets the first array.

```
df.select(
   col("Animal.Species").getItem(0).getItem("mammal").getItem("description")
)
```

Pseudo Logic:

```
col("Animal.Species").getItem(0).getItem("mammal").getItem("description")
+
col("Animal.Species").getItem(1).getItem("mammal").getItem("description")
+
col("Animal.Species").getItem(2).getItem("mammal").getItem("description")
+
col("Animal.Species").getItem(...).getItem("mammal").getItem("description")
```

Desired Example Output (flattened elements as string)

```
llama, sheep, rabbit, hare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not obvious, but you can use `.` (or the `getField` method of `Column`) to select "through" arrays of structs. Selecting `Animal.Species.mammal` returns an array of array of the innermost structs. Unfortunately, this array of array prevents you from being able to drill further down with something like `Animal.Species.mammal.description`, so you need to flatten it first, then use `getField()`.

If I understand your schema correctly, the following JSON should be a valid input:

```json
{
  "Animal": {
    "Species": [
      {
        "mammal": [
          { "description": "llama" },
          { "description": "sheep" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mammal": [
          { "description": "rabbit" },
          { "description": "hare" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```scala
val df = spark.read.json("data.json")
df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- Animal: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- Species: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- mammal: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)

df.select("Animal.Species.mammal").show(false)
// +----------------------------------------+
// |mammal                                  |
// +----------------------------------------+
// |[[{llama}, {sheep}], [{rabbit}, {hare}]]|
// +----------------------------------------+

df.select(flatten(col("Animal.Species.mammal"))).show(false)
// +------------------------------------+
// |flatten(Animal.Species.mammal)      |
// +------------------------------------+
// |[{llama}, {sheep}, {rabbit}, {hare}]|
// +------------------------------------+
```

This is now an array of structs and you can use `getField("description")` to obtain the array of interest:

```scala
df.select(flatten(col("Animal.Species.mammal")).getField("description")).show(false)
// +--------------------------------------------------------+
// |flatten(Animal.Species.mammal AS mammal#173).description|
// +--------------------------------------------------------+
// |[llama, sheep, rabbit, hare]                            |
// +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally, `array_join` with separator `", "` can be used to obtain the desired string:

```scala
df.select(
  array_join(
    flatten(col("Animal.Species.mammal")).getField("description"),
    ", "
  ) as "animals"
).show(false)
// +--------------------------+
// |animals                   |
// +--------------------------+
// |llama, sheep, rabbit, hare|
// +--------------------------+
```

Comment: This is an elegant and simple solution! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `explode` two times: first time on `Animal.Species` and second time on the result of the first time:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("tmp", explode(col("Animal.Species")))
  .withColumn("tmp", explode(col("tmp.mammal")))
  .select("tmp.description")
  .show()
```